# OpenLiberty JakartaEE with IBM MQ Resorce Adapater - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq, open-liberty

I'm upgrading an OpenLiberty application to Jakarta EE 9.1 that integrates with IBM MQ using it's JMS resource adapter.

Resource adapter is declared in the `server.xml` like this:

```xml
<resourceAdapter id="wmqjmsra" location="${server.config.dir}/wmq.jmsra.rar" />
```

This error blows up when the server starts:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] J2CA7002E: An exception occurred while installing the resource adapter wmqjmsra.
The exception message is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/spi/ResourceAdapter
```

As I mentioned I'm using Jakarta EE 9.1, so it is expected that class `javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter` will not be available since it has been renamed to **`import jakarta.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter`** following the new standard.

My `pom.xml` dependencyes:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The IBM MQ [Resource Adapter documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=applications-using-mq-resource-adapter) doesn't mention support for Jakarta EE, yet [it is supported](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=overview-jakarta-java-ee-8-in-liberty) in IBM Liberty.

So what would be a possible fix for this?

I'm using the latest IBM MQ Resource Adapter version 9.2.5.0, downloaded using [these instructions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=adapter-installing-resource-in-liberty#q128160_), and running the latest OpenLiberty build 22.0.0.4 and JDK 17.

Comment: Did you get this to work ? version 9.3.0.0 of MQ is ready but I still get the exact same exception when using 9.3.0.0 of MQ

Comment: @clausfod check this out =) https://github.com/epomatti/openliberty-jakartaee-jms-ibmmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQ does not yet ship a JMS3/Jakarta implementation. Version 9.3 has just been announced for availability in June and one of the features there is expected to be a JMS3 variant.

The current RA says it is supported in "any JavaEE 7.0 compliant version of IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty." Which obviously excludes the Jakarta EE systems for now.

Comment: Yep that's true, thanks. https://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_ca/9/897/ENUS222-129/index.html